# R: Reading dataframe into matrix

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm a newbie in R and can't figure out a simple problem.

I am looping through a data frame and inserting elements into a matrix but I get wrong data.

The result should be 53007 not 344. I don't even know where 344 is coming from.

Please help.

Thanks

```
   OpData <- read.csv2(file="OPData.csv",head=FALSE, sep=",")

x <- 1
Matx <- matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)

while (x<6) 
  {

    Matx[x,1] <- OpData[14,1]
    Matx[x,2] <- x
    x <- x + 1
    Matx
  }

Matx
OpData[14,1]
```

Results:

```
 [,1] [,2]
[1,]  344    1
[2,]  344    2
[3,]  344    3
[4,]  344    4
[5,]  344    5
> OpData[14,1]
[1] 53007
```

Comment: Can you verify that there are no bad values (anything that would force the first column to be read in as a string) in your csv file? If there is, `stringsAsFactors` will make that column a factor. If I'm not mistaken, when you subset a factor like you're doing, it will return the factor index instead of what you might think it should be.

Comment: I just want to add that it's possible that I'm confused and have things backwards, but this looks like a symptom of factors messing you up.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly by using iris ou mtcars data. could you show  us the result of str(OpData)? It might be a problem with the type of your columns(in particular the column you are using).

Answer (score 0):

It must probably be because read.csv2 read the column as factor. Its hard to judge without having the data. For now you should try :

`OpData <- read.csv2(file="OPData.csv",head=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Also you don't need the `Matx` at the end of `while loop`.

Even if this code works, you are gonna get same value over the 5 rows. Is it any good ?